Pytest internal app plugin not being discovered
I've been tring to get started with a basic Pytest internal app plugin. According to the v8.1.1 Pytest doc, loading MyPlugin.py in a test_TestPlugin.py file should be possible with pytest_plugins = ["MyPlugin",] in said test_ file. However, running pytest -s gives an ImportError: "No module named 'MyPlugin'".
Both plugin & test_ file are located in the same tests/ directory.
MyPlugin.py:
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl()
def pytest_runtest_setup(item:pytest.Item):
    print("Hook executed!")

test_TestPlugin.py:
pytest_plugins = ["MyPlugin",]

def test_quick():
    assert 1 == 1

I've tried:

Putting pytest_plugins in conftest.py instead. Gives same ImportError.
Prepending "MyPlugin" with the directory both plugin and test_ file are in: pytest_plugins = ["tests.MyPlugin",]. This DOES work, however is not expected nor prefered.

Any and all help is appreciated!

"however is not expected nor prefered." - The plugin has to be imported by that name, and if import MyPlugin in the same module doesn't work, this also won't work. So yes, this is the correct solution, as far as I understand.

@MrBeanBremen you're totally right! I expected calling pytest would add the cwd to sys.path, like is default behavior for calling python, but this is not the case. I'll start writing a detailed answer on how to 1. make cwd availabe using python -m pytest. 2. make the plugin importable using the standard methods (rel/abs import, install using venv) 3. add some info on why not to use __init__.py for good measure.

Loading plugins using the pytest_plugins variable also imports the plugin as a module. However, if import MyPlugin doesn't work, pytest_plugins = ["MyPlugin",] won't work either, as MrBean Bremen noted. Why won't importing MyPlugin work? Because calling pytest doesn't add the current working directory to sys.path. Though this is default behavior in python calls, says the 8.1.x doc.
Let's cover what can be done and shouldn't be done:
Add cwd to sys.path when running pytest
Adding cwd to sys.path can be done by calling pytest through python: python -m pytest.
Got this from the How to load custom plugin in py.test answer by user flub.
Use relative or absolute imports
As mentioned in the question, using pytest_plugins = ["tests.MyPlugin",] instead of just the plugin name will work.
Install the plugin using a virtual environment
By first turning the plugin into an installable package and then installing it, e.g. using a venv manager like pipenv or Poetry, will add the module to the sys.path: installed venv packages end up in the site-packages dir, which gets added to sys.path at runtime.
Avoid __init__.py to make your plugin importable
In this answer, user wim explains why using __init__.py to make the cwd appear on sys.path is not recommended and why venv installs or python -m pytest should be used instead. However, note that the answer is partly outdated: "the best reason not to rely on" __init__.py is no longer because Pytest will "make importlib the default in future releases". In the 8.1.1 doc: "the default will remain prepend for the foreseeable future", meaning __init__.py will continue to work (but is still not recommended).
